# Keep 0.1% samples to be outliers in HuberRegressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

When I run Huber regression on a certain data set using `HuberRegressor()` form `sklearn.linear_model`, I want to keep 0.1% of all samples to be outliers. As I know, HuberRegressor() controls the size of outliers by param `epsilon`, but the it doesn's support a percentage form, and my response variable **does not come from a normal distribution**.

The desired results are shown below

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import HuberRegressor

X = np.random.rand(100, 3)
y = np.random.rand(100, 1)
model = HuberRegressor(epsilon=?, fit_intercept=True, alpha=0)
model.fit(X, y)

>>> (model.outliers_).sum / len(y)
>>> 0.001
```

Further, is there a way to generally make such adjustments to models that use the huber loss function? Such as GLS+Huber or GBRT+Huber?

Answer (score 0):

I can only see one way to do this, and it is by running an iterative procedure to estimate the correct `epsilon` value.

In a toy example this would be like:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import HuberRegressor, LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

X, y, coef = make_regression(n_samples=200, n_features=2, noise=4.0, coef=True, random_state=0)

def find_epsilon(X, y, target_percentage, epsilon=1, tolerance=0.001, max_iter=100):
    for _ in range(max_iter):
        model = HuberRegressor(epsilon=epsilon, fit_intercept=True, alpha=0)
        model.fit(X, y.ravel())

        # Calculate the percentage of outliers
        residuals = np.abs(y - model.predict(X).reshape(-1, 1))
        median_abs_deviation = np.median(residuals)
        outlier_mask = residuals > epsilon * median_abs_deviation
        outlier_percentage = np.mean(outlier_mask)

        # Check if the percentage is close to the target
        if np.abs(outlier_percentage - target_percentage) < tolerance:
            return epsilon

        # Adjust epsilon
        if outlier_percentage > target_percentage:
            epsilon *= 1.1  # Increase epsilon if too many outliers
        else:
            epsilon *= 0.9  # Decrease epsilon if too few outliers

    return epsilon

# Target 0.1% outliers
target_percentage = 0.001
epsilon = find_epsilon(X, y, target_percentage)
```

now that we have the estimate fit the model:

```
# Fit the model with the calculated epsilon
model = HuberRegressor(epsilon=epsilon, fit_intercept=True, alpha=0)
model.fit(X, y.ravel())

# Check the final percentage of outliers
residuals = np.abs(y - model.predict(X).reshape(-1, 1))
median_abs_deviation = np.median(residuals)
outlier_mask = residuals > epsilon * median_abs_deviation
outlier_percentage = np.mean(outlier_mask)

print("Epsilon:", epsilon)
print("Outlier Percentage:", outlier_percentage)
```

this prints

```
Epsilon: 4.594972986357222
Outlier Percentage: 0.00115
```

very close to the desired 0.1% !

**Note**: The expression `outlier_mask = residuals > epsilon * median_abs_deviation` is a proxy based on the logic of the Huber loss function.